# What tool could I use to generate songs from text?

Tags: music, speech-synthesis

I stumbled with [this video](https://youtu.be/J8l6rTJRQrI?t=1m7s) showing a few songs generated by the built in text-to-spech tool in the game MoonBase Alpha. The tool in questions can "sing" the words so that it can be used for songs.

Is there a tool that can be used for that, other than MoonBase Aplpha's?

I guess such tool should support separation of words into syllables, using some meta notation, and also support intervals of silence, beside allowing to specify the pitch and duration of each note.

Answer (score 1):

Here are one app which generates songs from sms messages:

- [Ditty - Apps on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zya.ditty&hl=en_US)
- [Ditty by Zya on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ditty-by-zya/id957529556?mt=8)
- [Ditty For PC (Windows & MAC) | Techwikies.com](https://www.techwikies.com/apps-for-pc/ditty-for-pc-windows-mac/)